ID.ME digital Identity fails for organization
Within ID.Me we've had an organization setup for a few years now using OAuth to validate users are military, nurses, firefighters, etc.
Recently users have received the below error after selecting their group.
"This site no longer supports ID.me's digital identity verification technology. For thousands of live offers, please visit the ID.me Shop"


When checking the organization in ID.ME using the direct endpoint, it's the same behavior. Setting up a new application that's in sandbox works just fine.
No information on the developer docs shows a secret reset is require in OAuth after a set period and there's no information provided between group selection and it states it isn't supported. But new apps in the same org, callback URL, etc. all work.
Searching google for "This site no longer supports ID.me's digital identity verification technology. For thousands of live offers, please visit the ID.me Shop" has 4 results. Has anyone else run into a secret reset required for OAuth or anything similar?

After further conversation with the vendor ID.me, it was determined they turned off the service.
Either a new agreement needs to be setup, or other vendors considered.
